# How to find a button by cssselector

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
<div class="admin-welcome-hero">
   <h1>Welcome to the Meeting System</h1>
       <div class="admin-intro">
          Click on a current or previous meeting to edit or review details, or create a new meeting.
       </div>
       <button class="btn btn-lg new-meeting" ng-click="vm.newmeeting(this);"> 
         Create a new meeting 
       </button> 
   </div>
```

I have created the above button, that I need to 'click' through to selenium. This is my first workflow testing that I am doing, and I am having issue with this button, because it doesn't have an id.

I tried the following, and similar, even replacing with all three tags, and in combination.

What am I missing? Do I need to reference other html tags around it? Or can I focus on the button directly.:

```
var newMeetingButton = Driver.Instance.FindElements(By.CssSelector("btn"));
var newMeetingButton = Driver.Instance.FindElements(By.CssSelector(".btn"));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get a CSS Selector using Chrome dev tools

```
 1.Right-click on the element
 2. Select "Inspect"
     a. Chrome's DevTools will on on the Elements tab with the element highlighted (in blue)
 3. Right-click the highlighted element
 4. Select "Copy" > "Copy selector"
```

If the selector uses the class and the class is compound (class=".btn .primary") then replace the spaces with periods. Ex., ".btn.primary".

Comment: This is what I get back...assuming from being wrapped in other html tags #main-container > div:nth-child(2) > div > div.admin-welcome-hero > button  Would I just remove the spaces here? What do I do with this?

Comment: No need to remove the spaces. The tipoff is that it starts with #, which means ID, so it's not using the class attribute exclusively. So, FindsBy.CssSelector("#main-container > div:nth-child(2) > div > div.admin-welcome-hero > button"). You can test it out in the "console" tab of DevTools by doing document.querySelector("#main-container > div:nth-child(2) > div > div.admin-welcome-hero > button").

Comment: yes..that shows up in the console..so I would still do 'by cssSelector? because that still doesn't work...still wondering where my disconnect is.

Comment: could it be that Driver.Instance still has the previous page loaded? I have a wait in there to make sure it is at the right page, but it still has the previous page's title in it.....how can I make absolutely sure that I am on the right page if the 'wait' doesn't hold off? Or do I need to reinitialize something?

Comment: It opens up in a new tab...still focused on the old tab. I will look up how to change focus to the new tab....unless you can answer it sooner. I am sure all of these solutions will work once I find out about the focus.

Comment: So I navigated directly to the page, without a button, and of course this solution worked. Now I have to get approval to do this instead of a button click, or learn how to switch tabs if there is a way.

Comment: To switch to the newest Tab: driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandles.Last());

Comment: This did it...thank you very much...thanks for sticking through this question the last few days.

Answer (score 0):

The css selector you are looking for is:

```
By.CssSelector("button.new-meeting")
```

if you want to be more specific you can do

```
By.CssSelector("div.admin-welcome-hero button.new-meeting")
```

Hope this helps

Comment: You also can use:
 By.CssSelector("button[class='btn btn-lg new-meeting']")

Comment: thanks guys, but neither of these worked. I thought I tried Moe's first idea. But either way, neither of moes, or saura's post worked. What am I missing?

Comment: By.CssSelector("button[class='btn btn-lg new-meeting']") is a compund class, so it should be By.CssSelector("button[class='btn.btn-lg.new-meeting']")

Comment: If this did not work then i am willing to bet that there is an iframe on the page that you need to switch to. Can you share the full page source?

Comment: it isn't an iframe...but similar...a different tab...which I see is not supported in a 2016 post..not sure about now.

Answer (score 0):

The Cssselector for the particular element in the question has to be

```
Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.CssSelector("button.btn btn-lg new-meeting"));
```

or

```
Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.CssSelector("button[class='btn btn-lg new-meeting']"));
```

Below is the table for Cssselector syntax,
[image]

To get a complete hansdson using Cssselector, refer this=>[css selector](http://learn-automation.com/write-dynamic-css-selector-in-selenium/)

Comment: The above does not work either.  I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Oops... It has to be findelement and not findelements. Updated the answer. Tell me the exact err msg if it doesn't work

Comment: "Unable to locate element: button.btn btn-lg new-meeting"...this is with trying your first example.